# JQuery - Atualizar listagem por ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho um ajax que é chamado de 10 em 10 segundos por um setInterval, ele recebe um json e quando excluo um item do json preciso que o item suma da listagem do ajax tambem, o código pra remover o item da listagem é `$( "#item" + data.data[i].item ).remove();`, só preciso de um if para isso, segue exemplo:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.data, function(i, it) {
        if ( $( "#item-" + data.data[i].item).length ) {
             $( "#item-" + data.data[i].item+ " h2" ).html(data.data[i].item);
        }
    });
}
```

No exemplo ele atualiza o item que vem do json ajax...